# Get path of library - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, path, media

So I'm making a new instance of javafx Media class.

```
new Media("file://" + <path>);
```

The problem I'm having is I need to make the path to a class folder ("/music/launcher.wav") attached in Eclipse. I can get it to work in Eclipse by using the:

```
this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

Method and then adding .replaceAll("/bin/com/faris/game", "") but that's only a fix for Eclipse Debug and not the actual exported jar file. How do I get the location of a class folder in an exported jar file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this method:

```
this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

returns the jar file location (for issue with spaces check here [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file))
after you have the .jar location you must have your resources and let's say com/music/launcher.wav (com.music package), to get programmatically to your resource you must use the .jar location and add to this location your resource location like this:

```
String resources = "/com/music/launcher.wav";
this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()+resources;
```

you could add your resource as a library too, compressing it as a ZIP, but then you will need to decompress it for use via code (not hard but still more complicated), you can get to the lib folder the same way as resource, just replace the String resource like this:

```
String resoruces = "/lib/launcher.zip"
```

let me know if you could make it work, regards.

Comment: It worked in Eclipse but it didn't work in the Jar file. Thank you still because you gave me the idea of using new File(this.getClass().getResource(<resource>)).getPath();

Comment: ok, it should work in the jar file, want me to give you an example? maybe you are missing something.

Comment: No no, it's okay. The thing I said that you gave me an idea of worked.

Comment: Such a simple thing, and such a hard to find.. Super, it works on Windows and Unix systems. Very good, thanks :)